# Import external .exe file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, shell, pyinstaller, nmap

I'm trying to bundle my Python codebase into an .exe file using pyinstaller.

My code executes a shell command using nmap. This works fine in development because I have nmap installed separately on my dev environment.

However, if I want run this as an exe on another machine (without installing nmap separately on that machine) I can't seem to do this.

I've looked into the --add-binary option of pyinstaller and this is how I'm using it:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe";. --paths=path_to_my_python_file python_file_to_run -n name_of_my_exe_file
```

The resulting exe file is able to import Python specific dependencies and execute all the other Python code without any difficulties but it cannot run the nmap shell command.

This is how I'm running nmap through Python (full command omitted for brevity):

```
subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "nmap" )],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

1. Is it even possible to bundle nmap with my exe file?
2. If yes, am I doing it correctly?
3. If not, what are my options? (I can't use any python based nmap libraries like python-nmap etc.)

[UPDATE] Working Solution:
Final pyinstaller statement:

```
pyinstaller --paths=path_to_my_python_file --noconfirm python_file_to_run --noconfirm -n name_of_exe_file
```

Used robocopy to copy all the nmap files I needed:

```
robocopy  path_to_nmap_source_directory path_to_installation_destination_directory /COPYALL /E /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /nc /ns /np
```

Python code ([Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/54881911#54881911)) to get execution path of nmap:

```
def get_base_path():
    base_path = ""
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    return base_path

def get_exe_path(file):
    #file is the name of your exe file e.g nmap.exe
    base_path = get_base_path()
    exe_path = os.path.join(base_path, file)
    return exe_path
```

Comment: Why run it through powershell, which anyway won’t work if nmap.exe isn’t on the path, why not execute it directly?

Comment: Well in any case I need to bundle nmap with the exe file right?

Comment: You won’t have it to run unless you do - never tried bundling an exe but you can bundle binaries so why not try?

Comment: Okay I'm not quite sure what you're suggesting. Could you elaborate?

Comment: See the documentation e.g. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search

Comment: If you look at my pyinstaller command, you'll see that I have included the --add-binary option. I'm just not sure if that is the correct way to do it. That is what you're referring to right?

Comment: Looks good - all you need to do now is run nmap.exe from `.` relative to where the exe actually runs from - to get this location see the documentation https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html?highlight=_meipass#run-time-information also see this useful function `resource_path` in Jonathon Reinhart’s answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/54881911#54881911

Comment: I've added the binary like this 
```--add-binary "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe;." 
``` whereby ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe``` is where my actual nmap exe is stored. However, this still doesn't work.

Comment: Update your question with the details of the error you get, i.e. more than ‘still doesn’t work’.

Comment: Updated question with the working solution according to suggestions from @barny

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use a python implementation of nmap, there are many on pip such as [python-nmap](https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/), I would suggest downloading a pure python implementation and using that instead of an exe.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that there are python implementations. However, I can't seem to obtain the same level of detail I need with python-nmap. i.e the shell command returns more comprehensive information.